# Is there a way to find the fixed size subsequence sum in an N by M array that is the closest to a given N-dimensional vector?

Tags: dynamic-programming, linear-algebra, diophantine-equation

Basically, I need to solve the multivariate case of the "closest subsequence sum to a given value K" problem, which is solved with dynamic programming as far as I understand. Let's say I have M rows of integer data.

```
A = [
[a11, a12, .., a1n], 
...
[ai1, ai2, .., ain],
...
[am1, am2, .., amn]
]
```

And I have a target vector K:
`K = [k1, .., kn]`

In other words, I need to approximately solve the following system of linear equations:

```
w1*a11 + .. + wm*am1 = k1
...
w1*a1n + .. + wm*amn = kn
```

Where `w1..wn` can only assume values on 0 and 1, so it feels like a case of diophantine equations of sorts. I can't quite come up with a solution yet.

Another constraint is to have the closest subsequence of a fixed size, i.e. `w1+ ... + wm = S`. For example, I have 10000 rows and I want to find the 300 rows the sum of which will give me something close to my target vector K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be formulated as an instance of the [closest vector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Closest_vector_problem_(CVP)) in a lattice.

In particular, replace the vector $(a_{i1},\dots,a_{in})$ with the vector $(a_{i1},\dots,a_{in},c,0,0,\dots,K,0,\dots,0)$, where the $K$ is in the $i$th position, $K$ is a large constant, and $c$ is a small constant.  Let the target vector be $(k_1,\dots,k_n,cS,0,0,\dots,0)$.  Now look for the closest vector to the target, in the lattice spanned by the other vectors.

There are a number of algorithms for the closest vector problem, including using LLL lattice reduction to get an approximate solution.